# Computing Principal Logarithm on Different Intervals

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, logarithms

*Compute the principal logarithm of a complex number $z=\sqrt{3}+i$ using $\mathrm{Arg}(z) \in [0,2\pi)$ and $\mathrm{Arg}(z) \in (-\pi,\pi]$.*

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_logarithm) shows how the answer can be different for the example $z=-i$. On the first interval, the relevant angle is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ so your answer is $\mathrm{Log}(-i)=\ln(1)+i \frac{3\pi}{2}=i \frac{3\pi}{2}$. On the second interval the relevant angle is $-\frac{\pi}{2}$, so your answer is $\mathrm{Log}(-i)=\ln(1)-i \frac{\pi}{2}=-i \frac{\pi}{2}$.

However for the complex number $z=\sqrt{3}+i$, the relevant angle seems to be the same for both intervals, namely $\frac{\pi}{6}$. So my answer in both cases would be
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Log}(\sqrt{3}+i)
 &=\ln \left(|\sqrt{3}+i|\right) + i \mathrm{Arg} (\sqrt{3}+i) \\
 &=\ln \left(2\right) + i \frac{\pi}{6}
\end{align*}
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, your argument (pun intended) is correct. The complex numbers with different logarithm using those intervals would be the ones with negative imaginary part.